# inserting csv file data into mysql databse using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

[This is my html page for adding data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQwFp.png)

php script for inserting data into database placements and csv file into "eligilist" database. NOTE: the rownd1,rownd2.... are javascript event based on  number of rounds are selected then javascript code shows number of selection boxes which is rownd1, rownd2,rownd3 so these are the values based on user selection.

```
<?php
        require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
          $name = $_POST['placename'];
          $eligibility = $_POST['elig'];
          $backlogs=$_POST['blogs'];
          $rounds=$_POST['rownds'];

          if( isset($_POST["rownd1"]) && isset($_POST["rownd2"] ) && isset($_POST["rownd3"] ) && isset($_POST["rownd4"] ))
          {
              $round1=$_POST['rownd1'];
              $round2=$_POST['rownd2'];
              $round3=$_POST['rownd3'];
              $round4=$_POST['rownd4'];
          }
          elseif (isset($_POST["rownd1"]) && isset($_POST["rownd2"] ) && isset($_POST["rownd3"] )) {
              $round1=$_POST['rownd1'];
              $round2=$_POST['rownd2'];
              $round3=$_POST['rownd3'];
              $round4=NULL;
          }
          elseif (isset($_POST["rownd1"]) && isset($_POST["rownd2"] )) {
              $round1=$_POST['rownd1'];
              $round2=$_POST['rownd2'];
              $round3=NULL;
              $round4=NULL;
          }
          elseif (isset($_POST["rownd1"]))
          {
              $round1=$_POST['rownd1'];
              $round2=NULL;
              $round3=NULL;
              $round4=NULL;
          }

          $venu=$_POST['location'];
          $date=$_POST['InterviewTime'];

          $fileName = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
          $fileTmpName = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
          $fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          $allowedType = array('csv');
          if(!in_array($fileExtension, $allowedType))
          {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("invalid file extension")</script>';
           } else{

            $handle = fopen($fileTmpName,'r');
            while (($myData = fgetcsv($handle,1000,',')) !== FALSE){
                $fname = $myData[0];
                $regno = $myData[1];
                $branch = $myData[2];
                $percentage = $myData[3];
                $back_logs = $myData[4];
                $mobile = $myData[5];
                $email = $myData[6];

                 $query = "INSERT INTO eliglist (sr, fname, regno, branch, percentage, back_logs, mobile, email) VALUES (NULL,".$fname.",".$regno.",".$branch.",".$percentage.",".$back_logs.",".$mobile.",".$email.")";
          $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }

            $query1 = "INSERT INTO `placements` (`id`,`name`,`eligibility`,`backlogs`,`rounds`,`round1`,`round2`,`round3`,`round4`,`venu`,`date`) VALUES (NULL,'$name','$eligibility','$backlogs','$rounds','$round1','$round2','$round3','$round4','$venu','$date')";
          $query_run1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1);



          if($query_run && $query_run1)
          {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Successfully added")</script>';
          }
          else
          {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Error!")</script>';
          }

          }
        }
    }
  ?>
```

my problem is when i was submit all data along with csv file it shows error...but the except csv file remaining data are inserted into placements database the only problem with csv file not storing in eligilist table in databse...please help me and resolve my code if any errors...thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes round the field values in your insert (the same way you do it for the placements table)...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO eliglist (sr, fname, regno, branch, percentage, back_logs, mobile, email) 
           VALUES (NULL,'$fname','$regno','$branch','$percentage','$back_logs','$mobile','$email')";
```

BUT you should be using prepared statements and bind variables as this helps prevent several problems...

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO eliglist (sr, fname, regno, branch, percentage, back_logs, mobile, email)       
              VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $prep = mysqli_prepare ( $con,$query );
        $handle = fopen($fileTmpName,'r');
        while (($myData = fgetcsv($handle,1000,',')) !== FALSE){
            $fname = $myData[0];
            $regno = $myData[1];
            $branch = $myData[2];
            $percentage = $myData[3];
            $back_logs = $myData[4];
            $mobile = $myData[5];
            $email = $myData[6];

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($prep, "sssssss", $fname,
                   $regno, $branch, $percentage, $back_logs,
                   $mobile, $email );
            mysqli_stmt_execute($prep);
        }
```

Comment: Tq so much using blind variables is working........once again thank you.